# Python - Paramiko Client over SSL Socket - Non-Blocking Issue

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, sftp, paramiko

I wrote some Python code which enables the user to update my server with an edited HTML file and upload images. However I am encountering some issues with the connection.

On the server side I am running an Ubuntu virtual machine in VMware behind a pfSense router running HAproxy. The proxy enables users with the right client certificates to SSH into the right machine. Now this has been working for a long time now with no issues.

What I think my problem is, is within my SFTP code where the socket closes due to the SSL wrapper not being non-blocking. However I could not think or find a way of fixing my code. Especially since I am no expert using these packages. The Paramiko client and SFTP client have both been tested separately on the remote server with a VPN connection, they worked fine in that situation. Also the certificates the SSL socket uses work correctly.

**Versions:**
Python: 3.8.3
openssl: 1.1.1.f
paramiko: 2.7.2

```py
import socket
import ssl
import paramiko

class GE_SFTP_Client:
    def __init__(self, Username, Password):
        self.Username = Username
        self.Password = Password
        
        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH) # Verify Server cert
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile=_client_cert, keyfile=_client_key) # Load Client cert
        context.set_alpn_protocols(['ssh/2.0'])

        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.conn = context.wrap_socket(self.s, server_side=False, server_hostname=_target_host)
        self.conn.connect((_proxy_host, _proxy_port))

        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        self.connected_status = False
        SSH_Connection_Tries = 0
        while SSH_Connection_Tries < 4: # Try 4 times to connect.
            try:
                self.client.connect(
                                    hostname=_target_host, username=self.Username, password=self.Password,
                                    sock=self.conn, timeout=200, banner_timeout=200, auth_timeout=200
                                    )
                self.connected_status = True
                break
            except:
                SSH_Connection_Tries += 1
                pass

        if self.connected_status:
            self.sftp = self.client.open_sftp()
    
    def GE_SFTP_ClientEnd(self):
        try:
            self.sftp.close()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.client.close()
        self.conn.close()
        self.s.close()
```

An example of the ouput when using the paramiko SFTP client to get() a few images.

```
succes! /images/fulls/3.jpg
succes! /images/fulls/2.jpg
succes! /images/fulls/9.jpg
Socket exception: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately (10035)
```

Thank you, any advice you have would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't connect a TCP socket more than once, even if the connect failed. You have to close it and create a new one. I would be astonished if the SSL wrapper is non-blocking. This is one of the toughest programming tasks there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the idea of using the standard SSL wrapper from the SSL package and found a different way of doing things, namely with the asyncssh package combined with asyncio. Since together they provide me with the needed tools to tackle this problem.

The connection is now much more stable, even when downloading larger files. I hope this might help someone else as well! :)

```py
import socket
import ssl
import asyncio
import asyncssh

class SSL_Socket:
    async def create_connection(self, protocol_factory, host, port):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH) # Verify Server cert
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile=_client_cert, keyfile=_client_key) # Load Client cert
        context.set_alpn_protocols(['ssh/2.0'])

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((_proxy_host, _proxy_port))
        
        return (await loop.create_connection(protocol_factory, sock=s, ssl=context, server_hostname=host))

async def WorkingExample():
    async with asyncssh.connect(_target_host, tunnel=SSL_Socket(), username=Username, password=Password, known_hosts=_known_hosts) as conn:
        async with conn.start_sftp_client() as sftp:
            print(await sftp.stat(f'{remote_dir}/index.html'))
```